# MongoDB - Spring Data - Increment a field while saving on a condition

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have been working on an application using Java, Spring Boot, Spring Data and MongoDB. I have written a job to read a file and save the content in MongoDB. I use Spring Data, repository.saveAll(List of the entity class). I used a few fields in the file to create distinct ID so that if there is similar entry it will upsert the data.

There is a requirement to increment the count in a field of the corresponding document on a specific condition.

For example, I have a list of Persons(name, age and marks), I use the name as ID and save in db. While saving a new set of data in the next instance of Job, if the person has marks less than 35 (marks<35), increment the count as numberOfFailures and save in the corresponding document.

It may be possible to keep adding the marks to an array and fetch with a condition but its the count which is needed rather than the marks.

Please let me know if it is achievable. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

these are the annotations you can add an entity,

```
    @PrePersist @PreUpdate @PreRemove
    private void preValidate() {}

    @PostPersist @PostUpdate @PostRemove @PostLoad 
    private void postValidate() {}
```